# C# function which accepts name or ID as parameter

Tags: c#

Please let me know how can i write C# function which accepts name or ID as parameter

ie user who is using this function can pass either Id or name to the function.

i tried

```
getdetails(string name,Guid id)
```

but this asks both as required parameters for the user

Comment: It's referred to as [overloading](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx).

Comment: @restless i need either one of the parameters should be supplied mandatorily..cos in your code both were optional is"nt it??

Answer (score 3):

Generally the term you're looking for is "function overloading."  You can define both:

```
GetDetails(string name);
GetDetails(Guid id);
```

Perhaps even adding another option if *both* are available?:

```
GetDetails(string name, Guid id);
```

Internal to the object, those functions can call common shared code and their only differences would be how they handle their inputs.  In recent versions of .NET you can combine them into a single function with optional parameters:

```
GetDetails(string name = "", Guid id = new Guid())
```

In this case you'd have to check for the "magic values" of `""` and `new Guid()` within the function.  So while the signature may look cleaner in one way, the code may be worse in another.  Also worth noting is that with this approach *both* values are optional, so technically *neither* are required.  This might make it a little less clear, so I'd go with the former option of function overloading.

The point is that you have options available to you for this, and you should make sure you exercise the correct one if you find that the code you otherwise write is unclear or difficult to maintain.

Comment: either one of the parameters should be supplied mandatorily..cos in your 2nd code both were optional is"nt it??

Comment: @shiv455: Good point.  I'll make a note of that in the answer.  In that case overloading (writing two functions) is really the way to go.

Comment: But i need only one function,cant we use object type as parameter???please correct me if im wrong

Comment: @shiv455: Why do you need only one function?  The design requirements you've given so far call for two.  You *could* potentially use an `object` parameter for either a `string` or a `Guid` (this is often called "boxing"), but that would be a pretty awful design.

Answer (score 2):

Use overload's. One main function that will contain all the business logic and other functions that will use him with different overloads.
If you don't have a place where you need both, then the `public void getdetails(string name, Guid? id)` isn't needed.

Note: You need to do this carefully to avoid ambigious function calls.

```
public void getdetails(string name, Guid? id)
{
  // logic
  if(name != null){}
  if(id.HasValue){}
}

public void getdetails(string name){
  getdetails(name,null);
}

public void getdetails(Guid id){
   getdetails(null,id);
}
```

Comment: Would it make more sense to have the first method private?

Comment: What happens when you need both? If you don't then you should delete the first function and implement the two others. If you do it should remain public.

Comment: If you need both then absolutely keep it as public. But if you only need one _or_ the other (which was my assumption from the question), make it private or delete as you said.